Wallet Pass NFC usage for non-payment terminals
We have a scenario where we have multiple buildings that use a number of different NFC terminals for access control, and we would like to be able to create wallet passes that will grant access.
When reading the Event Ticket documentation here, the "Redemption options" mention the NFC tap via Google's Smart Tap is an option and that there is a list of certified terminal providers, but nothing is said about the authentication keys or merchant configs that are detailed when looking at point-of-sale terminals, loyalty cards and promotions.
I have been able to create an Event Ticket and Generic pass, via JWT, with Smart Tap set to true, our issuer number set as the Redemption issuer and a code as the Smart Tap value, but neither wallet entry have the NFC logo when added to the Google Wallet
Given that the passes are simply passing a code to a terminal to open a door, are we required to go through the documented setup for point-of-sale terminals? (authentication keys, merchant config, collector id, etc)
I have seen other pass providers offer access control passes, but these are usually paired with their own hardware or require an update to existing terminals which is not an option, and it would be great to not have to chase each ceritified terminal provider for an authentication key if possible

There are many different NFC specifications and technologies possible. Even if you do get the Google wallet to show your pass, the NFC access readers are unlikely to support the technology used for Google Passes unless they have been specifically designed to work with Google Passes.


Given that the passes are simply passing a code to a terminal to open a door, are we required to go through the documented setup for point-of-sale terminals?

It's doing a bit more than that. Terminals and the associated "tag" on the phone are doing ephemeral key exchange, and more. Take a look at the APDU traffic necessary just to read an Apple pass: https://www.passninja.com/tutorials/hardware/how-to-read-apple-vas-passes-using-an-acs-wallet-mate
Google's SmartTap protocol is very similar.
Long story short, you'll need a reader that conforms to the specifications for smarttap, which require keys and other credentials to be loaded onto the reader!
